# Using godoc to make API

Tags: go

I am writing a program in Go and have formatted my comments to assist in making documents. Does godoc have the ability to make my output look professional? Similar to what is seen on the Go website? I spent a long time and was able to get the information to display on the command line but running the http command always just brought up the Go homepage. I'm really at a loss for how to get it to display my code's comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you go to the `/pkg` folder of the generated golang.org site, you'll see your packages and everything installed by `go-get` among the standard library modules.

You can however go to the root source of either your `GOPATH` or the project you want to document, and try: `` godoc -http=":6060" -goroot=`pwd` ``

Comment: I've tried this. I even went as far to change my workspaces to reflect the src/pkg/.. that godoc looks for. Doing this i was able to get it to load my file dir. But it would show the source code not the doc's.

Comment: @DavidFirestone how does your library layout look like? I put my projects under $GOPATH/src which does the trick. Are you using this pattern? I agree that godoc is really tricky to use

Comment: I set up my project using the online tutorial. So I set $GOPATH to the base of my project.

Comment: @DavidFirestone your tree should look like `$GOPATH/src/my.namespace/myproject` thus running `go install` will put your executable in `$GOPATH/bin`, and all `go get` packages will also reside under `GOPATH/src`.

Comment: Correct which is how I had my files structured. I have a folder called gocode/src/pkg/string/ and all of the files reside in string. When i call godoc -http=:6060 it launches the files where I installed go. If i call it with godoc -goroot="gocode/src/" -http=:6060 I get my libary but it shows the source coe rather then the docs. I did discover that if I use the site localhost:6060/pkg that then I am able to view the docs. Everything I read though indicated i would just need the localhoust:6060. Thank you for all the help.